# Local internet presence for SEO

Tags: proxy, web-hosting, seo

I have a website hosted in the UK, but we're starting websites in other countries around the world.

I've heard that if the French version of your website is physically hosted in France, then it gets a better rank for people searching in France.

Problem is that I don't want to have to setup, pay for and administer another HA cluster in another country. I'd like to just set up some kind of invisible proxy - a back door to our main website in the UK.

Is this possible? or even advisable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to google the IP range is only used to determine the local country if the domain isn't country specific.  Eg. If you got a .fr domain name you should get the same rank boost on google.fr without moving your server or proxying

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can setup a Varnish proxy on a small box somewhere in France, proxying back to your main site.  It'll slow down most browsing, though, and is an extra complication, but it is possible.  We've setup similar systems for customers who need to host their app at their office but want their frontend on a fast network (our DC).  It works... fairly well.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I'll probably try the above, then this, to see if there's a difference.